# What is the computational complexity of the SOM algorithm?

Tags: self-organizing-maps, time-complexity

Assuming $m$ observations, $n$ features and $k$ nodes in the self organizing map, what is the complexity of the classic SOM algorithm? What would be the complexity of an ensemble of SOMs, where each SOM has a different number of nodes?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this paper (1)](http://arizona.openrepository.com/arizona/html/10150/106141/A_Scalable-98.htm),

$$ T = O(NC) = O(S^2)$$
where $T$ is the computation time, $N$ is the input vector size and $C$ is the number of document presentation cycles. $S$ represents the size of the sample.

[This site](http://users.ics.aalto.fi/sami/thesis/node33.html) seems to agree with $O(S^2)$.

(1):  Dmitri G. Roussinov, Hsinchun Chen.  A Scalable Self-organizing Map Algorithm
for Textual Classification: A Neural Network Approach to Thesaurus Generation

Comment: What does S stand for?

Comment: @user1603472 see above.  So computation time increases proportionately to (data_size)^2

Comment: Well, the SOM algorithm needs three loops 1) over epochs, 2) over samples, 3) over nodes/neurons.  So the number of vector comparisons will be the product of E*S*N.  Furthermore, the dimensionality D will determine the cost of the comparison. Of course, if any of them are thought of as constants, they will be dwarfed by the quadratic term in big-O analysis.  So I think this analysis does not give the entire picture.  Of course the running time will be different if the epochs are increased as well.